# Double File folder and strange simbol on the top

Tags: folder

i have 2 issues to my elementary Os. The first is the double icon of "file" in my menù,that redirect both to "Home" folder. The second one is the strange icon that appears in the top of my desktop(before IT). Can someone help me?[image]

[image]

Comment: Installed directly, Nemo comes with cinnamon desktop dependencies. To install it without such dependencies, un-install it, then try this solution [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/11/nemo-320-with-unity-patches-and-without.html).

Answer (score 3):

Elementary has no icons on the desktop, like yours, so you should have installed another file manager, such as Nautilus or Nemo. This is the reason for two icons for files.

About the second question,  you should have installed Dropbox,  so take a look at :

[dropbox for elementary os](https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox)

Comment: from my experience, Nautilus doesn't trigger this, but Nemo does.

Comment: Additionally, having two "Files" apps means that there are two launchers that are named "Files", which indicates two different file manager apps installed on the system.